# Julia threads hanging when > 10^7 loops

Tags: multithreading, julia

Julia script hangs if I set nloops to 10^8, runs fine at 10^7.

I execute using julia -t auto , using a 2021 Macbook Pro.

```
using Base.Threads

nloops=10^7
nt=nthreads()

println("nthreads: ",nt)
x=0

@threads for i in 1:nloops
        global x+=1
end

println("x= ",x)
```

Comment: I just downloaded the 64-bit 1.8.0 portable package of Julia on Windows and the code was working correctly (finished in <1s). Which version do you have? Can you try the latest? It might be a bug. Also please make sure you use a 64-bit version.

Comment: While it should not hang (I tested on my machine and it works too), do you realize this code is totally wrong?  you should have used locks (eg. a SpinLock) or atomic values

Comment: Thanks Jerome.  Przemyslaw: I have no idea what I'm doing, don't know what locks are.  I've seen atomic values but don't understand the underlying mechanisms.  If you could give me a three sentence tl;dr I'd appreciate it

Comment: Jerome, you fixed it haha.  Updated to 1.8.0 and it works now.  It's possible I wasn't running the ARM version before.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: For the lock and race condition I think you need to start with the basics: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf). Parallel programming is not as easy as it seems ;) .

Comment: Yeahh, oh how I wish I never had to think about it...  Thanks for the link Jerome!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply updating to 1.8.0 and making sure I downloaded the ARM version.  Credit to Jerome Richard.